# Installing CNTK on Ubuntu 18.04 for Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, ubuntu-18.04, cntk

I have installed CNTK on my ubuntu 18.04 for python 3.6 using pip. However, once I execute simple test, I'm getting an error.

**Simple installation test:**

> python3.6 -c "import cntk; print(cntk.**version**)"

**Error message:**

```
 UserWarning: Unsupported Linux distribution (ubuntu-18.04). CNTK supports Ubuntu 16.04 and above, only.
```

I have also followed the following link but I'm still encountering the error.

[Microsoft CNTK libmpi ImportError](https://tweaks-tips.blogspot.com/2017/12/microsoft-cntk-libmpi-importerror.html)

Comment: Does your python route to python 2 or 3? Conventionally, python refers to python 2.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the installation test script to python3.6... I've made sure it's python3.6

Answer (score 2):

It's just a warning.         The error is possibly about [openmpi library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/setup-cntk-on-linux#open-mpi).